# look for strings which are starting with . do not contain a . and end with _ any character : then any character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have strings like this:

```
fd.s_fdsfds.na233_OVERFLOW:fdsfdsfds
fds_f.dsfds.cs194_0.0-1000.0:fdsfds
fdsf.dsfds.abc333_0.0-1000.0:fdsfds
```

I want to match `na233` & `cs194` & `abc333`

so far I came up with this regex:

```
(?<=\.)(.*)(?=_.*:)
```

which matches `s_fdsfds.na233` and `dsfds.cs194` and `dsfds.abc333`

which is not what I want.

C# equivalent of what I want:

```cs
string s = "fds_f.dsfds.cs194_0.0-1000.0:fdsfds";
int colPos = s.IndexOf(':');
int underscore = s.LastIndexOf('_', colPos);
int prevdot = s.LastIndexOf('.', underscore);
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(prevdot+1, underscore - prevdot -1));
```

Comment: Please clarify: Wouldn't the first `s` of the first line [match your specifications](https://regex101.com/r/zrAcOh/1) too?

Comment: Replace `(.*)` with: `\w+`.

Comment: \w+ helps but it also matches an additional s in first line

Comment: `.*` matches as many characters as possible (*greedy*); `.*?` matches as few as possible (*non-greedy* or *lazy*). The former will happily gobble up all underscores but the last one; the latter will not. I expect you want a lazy match.

Comment: Your statement of the problem is incomplete. You merely give some examples and expect the reader to reverse engineer them to figure out the rules you are applying. That doesn't work generally and doesn't work here. Moreover, that won't work when writing code specifications, so you need to get used to being complete, prescise and succinct when writing SO questions. For example, you might state: "For a given string I wish to find the first substring containing at least two characters, none of which are underscores or periods, that is preceded by a period and is followed by an underscore"....

Comment: ...I can't say if that's an accurate statement of the question because I don't understand the question. It may be close but it's probably not what you are looking for. My point is that you need something like that. Incidentally, I said, "containing at least two characters" because, as @InSync observed, you aren't matching the string comprised of the first `"s"` in the first example.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I added the c# equivalent of what I want to do let me know if this is clear enough ...

Comment: Your C++ code suggests that you wish to extract the substring that is immediately followed by the last underscore preceding the last colon in the string, and is immediately preceded by the last period preceding the underscore just mentioned. Is that correct?

Comment: Its c# not c++ and not exactly I want to extract the string which has no periods but starts with period ends with _ any characters also could have period and :

Comment: Yes, I meant c#. I assume `s.LastIndexOf('_', colPos);` returns the last index of `'_'` in `s` that does not exceed the value of `colPos`. As I understand, if the string were `"a.b_c:d.e_f_g:h"` your code would return `"e_f"`. Is that what you want? If not, what would you want returned? Perhaps `"e"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first `.*` to `[^.]+` and the second to `[^_]*`:

```
(?<=\.)       # After a dot,
[^.]+         # match a sequence of characters not containing any dots
(?=           # which must be immediately followed by
  _[^_]*:     # an underscore, 0 or more non-underscore characters and then a colon.
)             #
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zrAcOh/2).

Here's a comparison table:

| Regex | C# |
| --- | --- |
| `:` | `s.IndexOf(':')` |
| `_[^_]*:` | `s.LastIndexOf('_', colPos)` |
| `\.[^.]*_[^_]*:` | `s.LastIndexOf('.', underscore)` |
| `(?<=\.)[^.]*(?=_[^_]*:)` | `s.Substring(prevdot + 1, underscore - prevdot - 1)` |

Since we don't want any empty match, it is better to use `+` (which means "1 or more") instead of `*` (which means "0 or more"): `(?<=\.)[^.]+(?=_[^_]*:)`.

Comment: this is great and thanks for also explain individual parts